# Algorithm for finding the lowest unused int in an NSArray of NSNumbers

Tags: objective-c, arrays, int

I strugle with this for second day...
I have an NSArray of ints, wrapped as NSNumbers. I need to find the lowest positive int, that is not present in the array.

Comment: so for example : `[3, 6, 4, 8]`, answer should be `0` ?

Comment: Yes. This seems like an extremely trivial question, I got like 5 responsesin 10 seconds..but I made my homework..conceptually i understand what i should do, but there is always some catch...
1) no suitable method in objective C
2) i am not good at mixing Ca and objC ..etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `NSMutableIndexSet` as an efficient way to store a set of integers. Just iterate over the array, stuffing them in the `NSMutableIndexSet`, and then when you're done, you can walk up the index set until you find a hole. Here's an example:

```
int lowestPositiveIntNotInArray(NSArray *array) {
    NSMutableIndexSet *set = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    for (NSNumber *num in array) {
        [set addIndex:[num intValue]];
    }
    // assuming 0 is a valid result here
    NSUInteger seed = [set firstIndex];
    if (seed > 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    NSUInteger next;
    while ((next = [set indexGreaterThanIndex:seed]) != NSNotFound) {
        if (next - seed > 1) {
            // there's a hole here
            break;
        }
        seed = next;
    }
    return seed+1;
}
```

Comment: The NSMutableIndexSet is great, it is automatically sorted. This, way I can extract the set of integers I will compare against without the need to sort them, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
int lowest = 1; // or zero

for (NSNumber *number in array)
{
    lowest = min ([number intValue], lowest)
}
```

EDIT: It seems I misread the OP

```
int lowest = 1; // or zero

NSArray *tempArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

for (NSNumber *number in tempArray)
{
    if ([number intValue] == lowest)
    {
        lowest = [number intValue] + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to find the lowest positive integer that's *not* in the array.

Comment: I am trying out everybody's suggestion to learn as much as possible. The problem with this version is that it iterates even after it found the not-used int. I sorted them being ascending, then it makes sense to iterate only untill the first nonused is found.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "simplest" version I could think of (note, simple, not most efficient, etc).

Simply, loop N times until you find a number that isn't contained. If you don't find one, then it must be the next.

This is also assuming that 0 is considered a valid answer.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [numbersArray count]; i++) {
    if (![numbersArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberFromInt:i]]) {
        return i;
    }
}
return [numbersArray count];
```

Comment: what if the array contains 10000 numbers, from 0 to 9999? That's going to be an awfully slow loop.

Comment: As I said, simple, not efficient. My assumption is this is homework, so, was giving him a start.

Comment: The condition in IF cycle can never be true (false false), the NSNumber object I would create inside it will always be a different object than any object inside my comparison NSArray even if there can be a NSNumber with the same int as my int I compare against. Or not?

Comment: Incorrect. NSArray's containsObjects uses "isEqual:", this is passed to NSNumber that uses logical equivalency to determine if two NSNumbers are the same. I.E. very different from using '=='.

Comment: @MarkPowell true, and remember that NSNumber Objects are constant, meaning once you create one with 'numberWithInt:' every subsequent call to 'numberWithInt:' will return the same object.

Answer (score 0):

- Sort the array
- Walk the array until you find a missing number.

Is there some more complicated requirement here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [quicksort](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) to sort array and take first ( or last it depends if sort is crescent or decrescent)

Answer (score 0):

I would do some thing like arranging the numbers in increasing order. Iterate over the list and stop and first positive number. If the **found number - 1** is still positive, then it is the least positive int or the **found number** itself is the least.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this? I put it in a unit test. If you're not familiar with the syntax, just look at the `for (NSNumber *num in listOfNumbers)` loop logic.

```
- (void)testExample {
    // setup
    NSMutableArray *listOfNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [listOfNumbers addObject:[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:6]];
    [listOfNumbers addObject:[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:4]];
    [listOfNumbers addObject:[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:12]];
    [listOfNumbers addObject:[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:-12]];

    // sort
    [listOfNumbers sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    // get the result
    int result = 0;    
    for (NSNumber *num in listOfNumbers) {
        if ([num intValue] > 0 ) {
            result = [num intValue] - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    STAssertEquals(result, 3, @"Was not 3");
}
```

You could do some other things such as add a `bool found` variable to notify that no positive numbers were encountered. Or your could optimize by reading the last value in the array - if it's negative, then all the values in the array are negative.

Answer (score 0):

### I was going after a comprehensive and less code answer. I compiled a solution using suggestions from @Richard J.Ross III, @MarkPowell and @Kevin Ballard, thank you guys.

I extract all my ints into a NSMutableIndexSet, which has a handy feature - it is always sorted, so we do not need a sortDescriptor. After that, I declare a lowest acceptable number. This is handy, since this way I can exclude 0. Then, I iterate the set until I find a "hole" in it.
I use the WHILE cycle, for me, it is the best approximation to common sense, ie while :) there is a number that matches my int, raise my int and try again. If no match anymore, the new lowest is the right one.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *mutableSetOfIDs = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

    for (Item *item in itemDatabase) 
    {
        NSUInteger x = item.ID;
        [mutableSetOfIDs addIndex:x];
    }


int lowest = 1;

    while ([mutableSetOfIDs containsIndex:lowest]) 
    {
        lowest++;
    }
    return lowest;
```